# Unity2d player collider entering trigger pressing key does not work

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a school project, and I need help with this trigger2dstay thing. I'm trying to make it were when my player's collider tag enters the triggers collider, an image pops up which works, but I'm also trying to make it were when the play does the same thing and presses <kbd>E</kbd>, it will trigger a animation, but when my 2d player walks in the trigger and presses <kbd>E</kbd>, nothing happens. pressing <kbd>E</kbd> only works when you are moving and pressing it, and not staying still.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class buttonele : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public GameObject Obje;
    public GameObject blockers;
    public GameObject eledoorn;
    public GameObject eledormation;
    bool Unlock;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Obje.SetActive(false);
        eledormation.SetActive(true);
        Unlock = false;
    }

    void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            Unlock = true;

            Obje.SetActive(true);
        }

        if (Unlock == true && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            Destroy(blockers);
            Destroy(eledoorn);

            eledormation.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("eleopen");
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            Obje.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please anybody! ANYTHING HELPS THIS IS LAST MINUTE!!!!

Comment: You just have to move the GetKeyDown Check and all the relevant code to your Update method, that should resolve the issue.

Comment: This question isn't about [tag:unityscript], it is about [tag:c#]

Answer (score 0):

The following code means that your player enters another player's collider, do you really want that?

```cs
if (other.tag == "Player")
```

---

To solve this problem, test the logic of the code. If you want your player to be able to use the <kbd>E</kbd> key by entering a certain area, you need to enter the tag of that place in this field. If you want the boxes to open, give them a special tag (`Item` for e.g) and change the code as follows.

```cs
if (other.CompareTag("Item"))
{
    // do something..
}
```